# Where is the configuration tab for naming a Google Chat Bot so that it can be referenced by Chat users?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, chatbot, google-chat

Trying to follow these instructions but can't find the configuration tab..

https://developers.google.com/chat/how-tos/bots-publish#enable_the_google_chat_api_formerly_hangouts_chat_api

I'm right at the last instruction - "4. Select the Configuration tab and enter the information for the bot, as described below."

From the prior instruction I am on the "APIs and services" > "Credentials" tab unless I've misunderstood that instruction. Where is the configuration tab? Rephrasing, where do I name my Chat Bot so that it can be referenced by users in Chat?

I'm aware this will be a stupidly simple solution but the instruction is currently a deadend for me.

Cheers for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Hangouts Chat API" once enabled will have a configuration tab.

[image: Configuration tab]

Comment: Thanks. I believe the core of my issue is that the company I am working for has restricted permissions on bots so I'm not getting the full view.